how to Flutter Firestore group documents by a variable?
I need to group several documents in the product collection, but I can't find a way to do it. I want to group them by 'color'. And I can't insert every color by hand, because the color is up to the ecommerce owner and always changes name.
here is my code:
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 400,
      child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text(
                'Caricamento...',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              );
            }
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              print(snapshot.error.toString());
            }

            return ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                  Map<String, dynamic> billo =
                      snapshot.data!.docs[index].data();
                  var newMap = groupBy(billo, (Map obj) => obj['release_date']);
                  print(newMap);

                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      CommonHomeHeader(
                        title: billo['color'],
                        onPressed: () {
                          ref.read(categoryIdProvider.notifier).state =
                              billo['id'];
                          context.push(RouteLocation.categoryDetails);
                        },
                      ),
                      CommonListView(
                        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.25,
                        itemCount: billo.length,
                        itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                          final product = billo[index];

                          return ProductoCard(product: product);
                        },
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
                });
          }),
    );
  }
}

I tried to group by and grouped_list but it says that I can use a map string dynamic in an iterable map dynamic

When you're using the following line code:
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').snapshots()

It means that you are reading all documents inside the products collection unordered. If you want to get the documents ordered by a specific field then you should call Query#orderBy() and pass the field name on which you want to order the documents and the direction, ascending or descending. In this way, you'll have a list of products sorted by their color, for example:
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('products').orderBy('color').snapshots()

This also means that you don't have to do any ordering on the client.

I already used orderby but it doesn't group them. I wanted something like this link where every document with the same 'color' where grouped in line

The simplest solution I can think of would be to create a list that contains in-term lists of products based on colors. For example, once you read the snapshots, iterate through the documents, and check the color. If the first three documents have the color set to red, add those documents to a new list, called redColoredProducts, and add this list to list the that contains all lists of colors.

the problem is colors change sometimes. I would like to impletement a code that find the documents where the colors is the same and group them in bundle. But when i try groupBy it says "type '_Map<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>' "

Yes, you can listen for changes, and once a new document with a specific color is added, add it to the corresponding list. Such an approach will update the UI in real time.

Hey Emanuele. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?
